# Android, getting the text from an edittext

Tags: java, android, regex

I am learning to program in Android and I have a question. 
I have an application with a TextView, a Button and a EditText and I want my application to:
I open it, I type something in the edittext and when I press the button, I want to check the text in the edittext if it's a valid email (using regular expressions) and display a message accordingly in the textview.

Comment: No, I know how to validate the email, I want to know what is the correct way to get the text from the edit text and check it.

Comment: use `findViewById()` and pass the ID of the text box, next call `getText()` on it

Comment: `I know how to validate the email,`. Then please look at the subject of your post. `I want .... to get the text from the edit text`. Then please adapt the subject of your post.

Comment: I have no idea whether you are asking about validating email addresses, validating an email's body (whatever that means) or ... simply getting the user's text from an `EditText`.  If you don't fix your Question to make this clear, it is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also check it without RegEx! You can put every character of the String into an Array of character. There you can check if there is a dot, a @ and so on...

```
private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN = 
        "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
        + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
```

This is the RegEx Expression -> Here is a Test Class

```
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class EmailValidator {
private Pattern pattern;
private Matcher matcher;

private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN = 
    "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
    + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

public EmailValidator() {
    pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EmailValidator em = new EmailValidator();
    boolean y  = em.validate("sakulreld@aol.com");
    System.out.println(y);
}



/**
 * Validate hex with regular expression
 * 
 * @param hex
 *            hex for validation
 * @return true valid hex, false invalid hex
 */
public boolean validate(final String hex) {

    matcher = pattern.matcher(hex);
    return matcher.matches();

}
```

}